# Raster data rendering incorrectly in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, rendering, macos

I just installed QGIS on a new Macbook and am experiencing problems. When I add a raster layer and zoom in and out, the position of the raster changes rapidly.

To illustrate the problem, below is a series of screenshots I took while zooming out from a vector layer of red points. As I zoom out, the relative position between the vector layer and a raster layer change. On the last two images, the points appear on top of the raster layer.

I am experiencing this with all raster layers and also basemaps. I've searched for similar questions but didn't find any.

**Question**: What is wrong and how can I fix it?

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

[![img4][4]][4]

[image: img5]

[image: img6]

I am using macOS Monterrey and QGIS 3.22.3. This is on a Macbook Pro 2021 with an M1 chip.

Comment: Did you georeference the raster layers, or are they geotiffs ? What projection/CRS are they in ?

Comment: Thanks, they are geotiffs. And the same happens when I load some basemaps (e.g. OpenStreetMap). So the files themselves are not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this by installing QGIS 3.16 LTR. But maybe someone has more insights into this problem.